# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user XXX

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, web-config

I'm deploying a web application on IIS 7.5, that web app has three kind of bikes for user to choose (Mountain Bikes, Road Bikes, and Touring Bikes). When I click each on it, I got a problems

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user XXX

And here is my **connection string**:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-AdventureCycle-20140110145435;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
<add name="AdvenBikesEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.BikesDB.csdl|res://*/Models.BikesDB.ssdl|res://*/Models.BikesDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework;User Instance=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="AdventureBikesDataEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.CategoriesBikesDB.csdl|res://*/Models.CategoriesBikesDB.ssdl|res://*/Models.CategoriesBikesDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework;User Instance=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="AdventureBikeDataEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.AdventureBikeDB.csdl|res://*/Models.AdventureBikeDB.ssdl|res://*/Models.AdventureBikeDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework;User Instance=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="AdventureBikesDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.AdventureBikesEntities.csdl|res://*/Models.AdventureBikesEntities.ssdl|res://*/Models.AdventureBikesEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework;User Instance=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="AdventureBikeDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.AdventureBikeDB.csdl|res://*/Models.AdventureBikeDB.ssdl|res://*/Models.AdventureBikeDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=TRUNGGEORGE-PC\MSSQLSERVER2012;initial catalog=AdventureWorks2012;Integrated Security=True;User ID=trung;Password=tuoi312;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

Could you please help me out of this? Thank you so much for your time :)

Comment: The "Integrated Security=SSPI" means use the credentials of the windows user. However if you're doing a web-site, configuration of IIS can change whether it's actually the user with the mouse, or the system user that IIS is running as.  Many web-sites create a specific user for the application and specify that in the connection string.  This reference site useful-ish: http://www.connectionstrings.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Greg has mentioned, Integrated Security=SSPI means that its using the windows account which is setup for the Anonymous User in IIS. Either one of three things you will need to do to correct the issue:

1) Add the user used by the worker process to the SQL database and assign the appropriate permissions.

2) Change the Connection String to use a predefined user name and password. Use http://connectionstrings.com to find out how to change this.

3) Change the Anonymous authentication credentials or the credentials used by the worker process.

If you need help completing either 1 or 3, let us know and someone will be able to walk you through it.