# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

This is the code, in SQL the columns `ID_C` and `CALLE` are `int` type, I am writing a C# app for add registry and the error is in the save button, in the int type textbox.

Someone help me!!

```
    private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cliente Cliente = new Cliente();
        Cliente.ID_C = txtID.Text= Cliente.ID_C.ToString();
        Cliente.NOMBRES = txtNombres.Text;
        Cliente.CONTACTO = txtCorreo.Text;
        Cliente.CALLE = txtCalle.Text;
        Cliente.NUMERO = txtNumero.Text= Cliente.NUMERO.ToString();
        Cliente.COLONIA = txtColonia.Text;
        Cliente.FECHA_ALTA = txtFecha.Text;

        int resultado = ClienteDAL.Agregar(Cliente);

        if (resultado > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Datos guardados con exito", "Datos Guardado", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No se grabaron los datos", "Error al guardar", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }

    }

    private void btnCerrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, use search before asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int

Comment: What do you think the error means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse your `string` values into `int`:

```
Cliente.ID_C = Int32.Parse(txtID.Text);
Cliente.CALLE = Int32.Parse(txtCalle.Text);
```

To make it more robust, you can use [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: thank u so much, but another error appear: sqlException was unhandled: SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("Data source=VICTOR-PC; Initial Catalog=KAZIIM; Integrated Security=True;"); Conn.Open();

Comment: @VictorHernandez Please, give more details about the unhandled SqlException. Also post it as another question.

Comment: i cant post it in 90 minuts, the error say "Login failed for user ''." in System.data.sqlclient.sqlexcention... i use windows autentication and the error is in "conn.open();" line

Answer (score 0):

Use it Like this:-

```
       Cliente.ID_C = Int32.Parse(txtID.Text);
       Cliente.CALLE = Int32.Parse(txtCalle.Text);
```

Comment: thank u so much, but another error appear:



sqlException was unhandled

SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("Data source=VICTOR-PC; Initial Catalog=KAZIIM;  Integrated Security=True;");
           Conn.Open();

Comment: can you give Exception Details?? @VictorHernandez

Comment: the error say "Login failed for user ''." in System.data.sqlclient.sqlexcention... i use windows autentication and the error is in "conn.open();" line... error number 18456

Comment: Check Your Data Source Name and Database Name Again and try to Connect it using Sql server...

Comment: the data source name and database name are corrects and the error continues

Comment: Try this:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180474/system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-login-failed-for-user-xxx

Comment: i tried but not working in my app, now the error is other:  System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=El formato de la cadena de inicialización no se ajusta a la especificación que comienza en el índice 73.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
       en System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
       en